# KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

When I use `cx_Freeze` I get a keyerror `KeyError: 'TCL_Library'`while building my pygame program. Why do I get this and how do I fix it?

My setup.py is below:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Snakes and Ladders",
    version = "0.9",
    author = "Adam",
    author_email = "Omitted",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                         "include_files": ["main.py", "squares.py",
                         "pictures/Base Dice.png", "pictures/Dice 1.png",
                         "pictures/Dice 2.png", "pictures/Dice 3.png",
                         "pictures/Dice 4.png", "pictures/Dice 5.png",
                         "pictures/Dice 6.png"]}},
    executables = [Executable("run.py")],
    )
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can work around this error by setting the environment variables manually:

```
set TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6
set TK_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6
```

You can also do that in the `setup.py` script:

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6'

setup([..])
```

---

But I found that actually running the program doesn't work. On the [cx_freeze mailinglist it was mentioned](https://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/cx-freeze-users/?viewmonth=201512):

> I have looked into it already and no, it is not just a simple recompile --
>   or it would have been done already! :-)
>
> It is in progress and it looks like it will take a bit of effort. Some of
>   the code in place to handle things like extension modules inside packages
>   is falling over -- and that may be better solved by dropping that code and
>   forcing the package outside the zip file (another pull request that needs
>   to be absorbed). I should have some time next week and the week following
>   to look into this further. So all things working out well I should put out
>   a new version of cx_Freeze before the end of the year.

But perhaps you have more luck ... [Here's the bug report](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/155/required-environment-variables-tcl_library).

Comment: Sorry for the wait. Thank you for helping, I haven't got this to work.

Comment: Happens also in python 3.6.1/2

Comment: copy `tk86.dll` and `tcl86.dll` to the binary path can solve run-time error

Answer (score 36):

Instead of setting the environment variables using installation specific absolute paths like `C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\...` you may also derive the necessary paths dynamically using the `__file__` attribute of Python standard package like `os`:

```py
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
```

After this fix the executable file will be created, but you will probably get a "DLL not found error" when you try to execute it - at least with Python 3.5.3 and cx_Freeze 5.0.1 on Windows 10.

When you add the following options, the necessary DLL-files will be copied automatically from the Python-Installation directory to the build-output of cx-Freeze and you should be able to run your Tcl/Tk application:

```py
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
         ],
    },
}

# ...

setup(options = options,
      # ...
)
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly! I didn't even get a `DLL not found error`, so no need to add extra options as specified in the second part of your answer. I have Python 3.6 and my py-app uses Tkinter/TCL.

Comment: For cx_Freeze version 5.1.1, the DLLs need to be copied into a subdirectory `lib` of the build directory, see how in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495955/8516269).

Answer (score 15):

Just put this before the setup at setup.py

```
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"
```

And run it:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you get following error with python 3.6:

```
copying C:\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6 -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\tcl
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
```

Simply create `LOCAL_TO_PYTHON` dir in `C:\` then create `Python35-32` dir inside it. Now copy `tcl` dir from existing `Python36` dir (in `C:\`) into `Python35-32`.

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you get following error with python 3.6:

copying `C:\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6` -> `build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\tcl`
error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6'`

Simply create LOCAL_TO_PYTHON dir in C:\ then create Python35-32 dir inside it. Now copy tcl dir from existing Python36 dir (in C:) into Python35-32.

Then it works fine.

**I did this steps and created a .exe file into the  build dir but if ı try to click app dont wait on the screen instantly quick, my codes here **

```
from tkinter import *
import socket



window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x150")
window.title("IpConfiger")
window.config(background="black")

def goster():
    x=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    label=Label(window,text=x,fg="green",font=("Helvetica",16))
    label.pack()
def information():
    info=Label(window,text="Bu program anlık ip değerini 
    bastırır.",fg="green",font=("Helvetica",16),bg="black")
    info.pack()


information()
tikla=Button(window,text="ip göster",command=goster)

tikla.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

[D. L. Müller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034479/8516269) need to be modified for cx_Freeze version 5.1.1 or 5.1.0. In these versions of cx_Freeze, packages get frozen into a subdirectory `lib` of the build directory. The TCL and TK DLLs need to be moved there as well. This can be achieved by passing a tuple `(source, destination)` to the corresponding entry of the `include_files` list option (see the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe)).

Altogether the `setup.py` script needs to be modified as follows:

```py
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

# ...

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))
         ],
    },
}

# ...

setup(options = options,
      # ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial KeyError problem:

[image: KeyError]

This worked for me with python 3.7 on windows 7:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

where = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = where+"\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = where+"\\tcl\\tk8.6"

build_exe_options = {"include_files": [where+"\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll", where+"\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll"]}  


setup(
    name = "SudoCool",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Programme de SUDOKU",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},  
    executables = [Executable("sudoku.py")]
)
```

Now cx_Freeze is working:
[image: it's working]

[image]

[image]

My application is working:
[image]