# KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY' comes out when I use cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm using Python 3.

When I use cx_Freeze, the KeyError comes out.

I tried both `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py bdist_msi`, but both didn't work.

Here's my setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "SnakeGame",
    executables = [Executable("SnakeGame.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706103/7957705

Comment: I tried writing something on my setup.py file, but it didn't work.

Comment: And I don't know what do other things mean. Could you tell me how can I do them?

Comment: if you working on windows run this `python -c "import os;PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__));os.system('set TCL_LIBRARY={}'.format(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')));os.system('set TK_LIBRARY={}'.format(os.path.join(
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')))"`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, so I changed my setup.py code. On the site you recommanded, they said I should add `import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6') os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')`, so I tried it. Then, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' came out. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: you should give much more info about error which part of code `AttirubeError`