# Pyinstaller .py to .exe with Sklearn classifier

Tags: python, pyinstaller, importerror

I've been trying to convert a `.py` file to a `.exe` file for 2 days now with no luck. I've gotten the farthest with `pyinstaller` but went I launch the `.exe` it closes (import errors). In the warning file it has errors such as

```
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request
```

If you need the entire list I can give it to you but it's over 300 lines. I've tried the following with pyinstaller with no luck

- Creating a single file exe
- Creating a single directory exe
- Removing all path altering code
- Creating a exe with the noupx option
- Putting just the files I need in a directory and creating it (I had other related files that I thought it might be messing up on)

I am using the following

- Windows 7 pro
- Python 3.6 Anaconda 5.2.0
- VS code (is this relevant?)

My `.py` file basically runs a pre-made sklearn classifier. The classifier for the `.py` is in the same directory exported and imported using pickle (file name is `clf.pickle`). Any help would be appreciated and if you need more info please ask. Thanks.

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python .

Comment: I've tried that many times but only get `KeyError: 'TLC-Library'`

Comment: For the KeyError please try the information provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze

Comment: @Arihant Thanks! Now my error is that not all my spicy files are there. I think I'm doing something wrong.