# Impossible to build python with cx_freeze

Tags: cx-freeze

On my professionnel computer, i've managed to install on a specific open folder the ananconda sw and the cx_freeze libs.

However when I want to build a python files in another folder here  :

Do you have any idea what is the problem? Limitation of the IT departement in any proxy? Bad installation of cx_freeze? bas usage of it?

[error compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps1cV.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/35533803/8516269 ?

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages, copy and paste or type the actual message into the post directly.