# Error after converting tkinter program to exe using cx_Freeze and running the exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, exe, cx-freeze

I've spent hours trying to find how to fix this problem but I haven't been able to find anything helpful yet.
So I'm trying to convert a tkinter program to exe using cx_Freeze. Everything works well until I try to open the actual exe file [Here's is the error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpPaB.png).

My setup file:

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"

build_options = dict(
    packages=['sys'],
    includes=['tkinter'],
    include_files=[(r'C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll',
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                   (r'C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll',
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))]
)

executables = [
    Executable('app.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='simple_Tkinter',
      options=dict(build_exe=build_options),
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze tkinter script',
      executables=executables,
      )
```

and my script:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Application', font='Tahoma 15 bold italic').pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

So if you have any idea what could/is causing the error please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer edited after the OP has modified the question)

I guess something is wrong with the `os.environ` definitions. They should point to TCL/TK directories, not to the DLLs. These definitions should read something like:

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Osborne-Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6"
```

Anyway, it would be much better to let the setup script find dynamically the location of the TCL/TK resources as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034479/8516269):

```
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

build_options = dict(
    packages=['sys'],
    includes=['tkinter'],
    include_files=[(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                   (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))]
)
```

Comment: I did what you said and now I'm getting a different error. So I edited the setup file and the error report image from my question to what they look like now.

Comment: @Goodester I have edited my answer according to your modified question. Please also put the error message as text instead of image if possible.